# Auto attach file on email reporting program vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Here is my program for auto email with manual attachments on certain time using config.ini for email username and password

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Timers

Public Class Form1
Dim file(2) As String   
Dim pesan As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Text = "Water Monitoring"    
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub kirim()  'step send e-mail manual'
    Try
        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim txtEmail As String
        Dim txtPassword As String
        txtEmail = Module1.Read_INI("GENERAL", "Email")
        txtPassword = Module1.Read_INI("GENERAL", "Password")
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(txtEmail, txtPassword) 'login email'
        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.Timeout = 3000000
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        e_mail = New MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress(txtEmail)
        e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text)
        e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        e_mail.Body = pesan
        If Not txtFile1.Text = Nothing Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(txtFile1.Text)
            e_mail.Attachments.Add(attach)  'attach attachment 1
        End If
        If Not txtFile2.Text = Nothing Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(txtFile2.Text)
            e_mail.Attachments.Add(attach)  'attach attachment 2
        End If
        If Not txtFile3.Text = Nothing Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(txtFile3.Text)
            e_mail.Attachments.Add(attach)  'attach attachment 3
        End If
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
        MsgBox("Mail Sent")

    Catch error_t As Exception
        MsgBox(error_t.ToString)    'message box error
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub chckboxAuto30s_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chckboxAuto30s.CheckedChanged
    If chckboxAuto30s.Checked = True Then
        btnSend.Visible = False
    Else
        btnSend.Visible = True  
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtMessage_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtMessage.TextChanged
    pesan = txtMessage.Text
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancelAllAttachments_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancelAllAttachments.Click
    txtFile1.Text = ""
    txtFile2.Text = ""
    txtFile3.Text = ""
    file = Nothing  
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddAttachments_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddAttachments.Click
    file = Nothing
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    file = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames

    txtFile1.Text = file(0)
    Try
        txtFile2.Text = file(1)
    Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
    End Try
    Try
        txtFile3.Text = file(2)
    Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException    'attach file attachment'
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    kirim() 'send e-mail manual'
End Sub

Private Sub btnClearText_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearText.Click
    txtTo.Text = ""
    txtSubject.Text = ""
    txtMessage.Text = ""    
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim timerforAuto As Date
    timerforAuto = CDate(timeAuto.Text)
    If timerforAuto.Hour = Now.Hour And timerforAuto.Minute = Now.Minute And timerforAuto.Second = Now.Second Then
        kirim()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

My question is, how to setting the attachments is choosed automatically? I want to attach file automatically based on current time.

For example : i want to attach

C:\testing1.xlsx

C:\testing2.xlsx

automatically. And refresh the file if the file contents in the xlsx have changed every day.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `kirim()` call in the `timer1_tick` to accept a date parameter.

```
Public Sub kirim(TimeKickedOff as Date)  'step send e-mail manual'
    Try
        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim txtEmail As String
        Dim txtPassword As String
        txtEmail = Module1.Read_INI("GENERAL", "Email")
        txtPassword = Module1.Read_INI("GENERAL", "Password")
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(txtEmail, txtPassword) 'login email'
        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.Timeout = 3000000
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        e_mail = New MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress(txtEmail)
        e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text)
        e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        e_mail.Body = pesan
        If Not txtFile1.Text = Nothing Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(txtFile1.Text)
            e_mail.Attachments.Add(attach)  'attach attachment 1
        End If
        If Not txtFile2.Text = Nothing Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(txtFile2.Text)
            e_mail.Attachments.Add(attach)  'attach attachment 2
        End If
        If Not txtFile3.Text = Nothing Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(txtFile3.Text)
            e_mail.Attachments.Add(attach)  'attach attachment 3
        End If
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
        MsgBox("Mail Sent")

    Catch error_t As Exception
        MsgBox(error_t.ToString)    'message box error
    End Try

End Sub
```

Change the call in `timer1_tick` to pass the time it was kicked off to `kirim`.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim timerforAuto As Date
    timerforAuto = CDate(timeAuto.Text)
    If timerforAuto.Hour = Now.Hour And timerforAuto.Minute = Now.Minute And timerforAuto.Second = Now.Second Then
        kirim(timerforAuto)
    End If
```

End Sub

In the `kirim(TimeKickedOff as Date)` sub add code that tests the `TimeKickedOff` to the datetime you want each attachment attached to the email, for example, in the `kirim` sub where `SomeTime` = the datetime you want the file attached:

```
    If Not txtFile3.Text = Nothing Then
        if TimeKickedOff.Hour = SomeTime.Hour And TimeKickedOff.Minute = SomeTime.Minute And TimeKickedOff.Second = SomeTime.Second Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(txtFile3.Text)
            e_mail.Attachments.Add(attach)  'attach attachment 3
        End If
    End If
```

To test if a file has changed, you can handle this in the timer event.  Dim a static variable that contains the content of the file and check to see if the content changes every so often and if the content changes do what you need to do when that happens and load the new content into the static variable so you can keep checking for newer changes.